# How to change the primary key value in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL server 2014.

In my table, I set primary key for the column.The primary key value starts from 1. I want to change it to start from 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't.  The purpose of a primary key is to uniquely identify each row.  If you change the value, then you break the link between the value and the row.

Comment: you mean in an existing table or for a new table ? For existing tables you dont.

Comment: In existing table, i want to change primary key value to start from 0.

Comment: If this table is used by another table as foreign key than your relations will get messed up. In that case this is impossible without changing all the values from all foreign key on all tables that relate to this one

Answer (score 4):

this creates a table where the autoinc fields starts with 0 in stead of 1
Also it is best to name your primary key

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    id int IDENTITY(0,1),
    othercolumn int,
    and so on...

    constraint PK_myTableID primary key (id)
)
```

If however you want to do this with an existing table than your best option is to use [Element Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6832943/element-zero)'s anwser

Answer (score 4):

If the table is empty, the easiest thing to do would be to drop the table and recreate it with an identity seed of 0 like [GuidoG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139039/6832943) did.  If the table has data, changing the primary key to a 0 (like [Intern87](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139013/6832943) mentions) would be a bad idea because after it inserts a row with a key of 0 the next key would be 1 which would probably already be in the table and therefore would cause further inserts to fail with a primary key duplication error.

So if you have existing data but you MUST have data with a key of 0, I would probably just do an identity insert with row 0.  Do this with the following

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON;

INSERT INTO mytable (id, col1, col2, etc..) 
VALUES (0, 'col1data','col2data', etc..);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable OFF;
```

just make sure to run all of that at once because once you turn identity insert on then other inserts may fail till you turn it off.

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: This seems like the best option for an existing table, because you can leave all the key values of all other records unchanged and simply insert a new record with keyvalue 0. So +1 from me

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to reseed it;

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 0);
GO
```